Translating RestTemplate to WebClient, PUT with empty Body
I have this code in Java 8 using RestTemplate.
@Override
public ResponseCambioEstadoDTO actualizarLead(String idLead) {

    Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
    uriVariables.put("idLead", idLead);

    UriComponents builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(urlActualizarLeadValidacion)
    .buildAndExpand(uriVariables);

    ResponseEntity<ResponseCambioEstadoDTO> respuestaLeadActualizado;
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        respuestaLeadActualizado = restTemplateMs.exchange(builder.toUriString(),
                HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(null, headers), ResponseCambioEstadoDTO.class);
        return respuestaLeadActualizado.getBody();
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        log.error("ERROR... Bla, Bla");
        throw e;
    }
}

In my previous code I have:
respuestaLeadActualizado = restTemplateMs.exchange(builder.toUriString(),
    HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(null, headers),  ResponseCambioEstadoDTO.class);

The new HttpEntity<>(null, headers) is using a body with null value.
Here my code using Spring WebClient in Java 11.
  @Override
  public ResponseCambioEstadoDTO actualizarLead(String idLead) {

    Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
    uriVariables.put(ID_LEAD, idLead);

    String urlEndpoint = msLeadsClienteNegConfiguration.getUrlLeadsEstadoValidacionActualizar();
    String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(urlEndpoint)
        .buildAndExpand(uriVariables)
        .toUriString();

    URI uri = URI.create(url);
    try {

      return webClient.put()
          .uri(uri)
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(ResponseCambioEstadoDTO.class)
          .block();

    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
      log.error("ERROR... Bla, Bla");
      throw e;
    }
  }

As you can see the webClient doesn't have body.
      return webClient.put()
          .uri(uri)
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(ResponseCambioEstadoDTO.class)
          .block();

Previously I was trying with:
        return webClient.put()
                .uri(uri)
                .bodyValue(null)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ResponseCambioEstadoDTO.class)
                .block();

Is it that allowed?
Is needed to indicate that the body request is empty?
